# how to get the list of xml files from document directory

Tags: iphone, xml

I am developing an application. I want to get the names of all .xml files from a document directory, So please tell me how to do this one.

Comment: Steps:1. Loop through the directory and get all files 2. Check each file which ends with .xml. This will give you the list of all xml file in a directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *xml_path = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xmlfolder"]; // if you have folder 
NSArray *list =[NSBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"xml" inDirectory:xml_path];
NSLog(@"%@",list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docPath error:nil];
NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.xml'"];
NSArray *xmlFiles = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
```

Comment: This kill the applciation at line NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@".xml"];